# How to send picture as an attachment with sms programmatically?

Tags: iphone, sms

I want to send a picture via an iphone app.

Since it's not possible to send MMS, I found some answers speaking about sending the picture as an attachment with the SMS. How to do that programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure if the Iphone has any specific extensions for iphone-to-iphone image sharing, but SMS with attachments is essentially MMS. What they may be doing is uploading the image to some hosting site and then sending the URL as plain text in an SMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
    MFMessageComposeViewController *sms = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [sms setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
    [sms setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"123-4567"]];
    [sms setSubject:@"Subject"];
    [sms setBody:@"Body"];
    [sms addAttachmentData:myData typeIdentifier:@"type" filename:myFile];
    [sms setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:sms animated:YES completion:NO];
```

Hope it helps.